# Reopen review queue shows the edit made over two years ago?

Tags: support, review

I just performed a review in the reopen queue on a post that appears to have entered the queue due to an edit. So far, nothing unusual.
The unusual thing is that the edit was made *over two years ago*.

For reference, this is the review in question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80457

Could anyone explain what happened here? When performing the review, I was convinced that it would be an audit, but it turned out it was a regular review.

Comment: as far as I can see, someone recently cast reopen vote on it - this pushed it into queue, not the edit. The fact that review presented it as a result of edit looks like a bug